# Running commands from Powershell

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and am learning via online tutorials. On Study Drill #6 for example 15 [on this page](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex15.html), I'm trying to open up the 'ex15_sample.txt' file that I have created and exists.

This is what it says to do:

> Start 'python' to start the Python shell, and use 'open' from the prompt just like in this program. Notice how you can open files and run 'read' on them from within 'python'?

In the command prompt, I entered `python` to start the Python shell and have tried typing in the following, which threw me an error:

`open(ex15_sample.txt)`

The error I get is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ex15_sample' is not defined`

`ex15_sample.txt` is a file that exists in the same folder. How am I supposed to use `open` or any other command from the prompt? I am running Python 2.7.8 on Powershell, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `open` is a string containing the filename.

Just put the file name in **quotation marks:**

```
f = open('ex15_sample.txt')
```

Comment: Ok, I did that and it didn't open but it threw me this: `<open file 'ex15_sample.txt', mode 'r' at 0x0000000001F54150>`

Comment: that means file is open , you can put it in a variable an work with it. please read this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). check my edit.